# Custom post type won't display, IS homepage & main query

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have a custom post type that worked just fine earlier, but not anymore. I haven't installed any new plugins and my code seems perfectly valid. Other custom fields are showing (default post type), but the ones I'm talking about not anymore.

Here's the code:

```
// Show posts of 'post', 'homepage_slider' post types on home page
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'add_my_post_types_to_query' );

function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'homepage_slider' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

As you can guess, `homepage_slider` is my Custom Post Type. I haven't tweaked it's code one bit, but here it is just for reference:

```
    function homepage_slider() {

$labels = array(
    'name'                => 'Images',
    'singular_name'       => 'Image',
    'menu_name'           => 'Homepage Slider Images',
    'parent_item_colon'   => 'Parent Image:',
    'all_items'           => 'All images',
    'view_item'           => 'View Image',
    'add_new_item'        => 'Add New Image',
    'add_new'             => 'Add New',
    'edit_item'           => 'Edit Image',
    'update_item'         => 'Update Image',
    'search_items'        => 'Search Image',
    'not_found'           => 'Not found',
    'not_found_in_trash'  => 'Not found in Trash',
);
$args = array(
    'label'               => 'homepage_slider',
    'description'         => 'Homepage Slider',
    'labels'              => $labels,
    'supports'            => array( 'title', 'thumbnail' ),
    // 'taxonomies'          => array( 'category', 'post_tag' ),
    'hierarchical'        => false,
    'public'              => true,
    'show_ui'             => true,
    'show_in_menu'        => true,
    'show_in_nav_menus'   => true,
    'show_in_admin_bar'   => true,
    'menu_position'       => 5,
    'menu_icon'           => 'myurl',
    'can_export'          => true,
    'has_archive'         => false,
    'exclude_from_search' => true,
    'publicly_queryable'  => true,
    'rewrite'             => false,
    'capability_type'     => 'page',
);
register_post_type( 'homepage_slider', $args );
```

}

```
// Hook into the 'init' action
add_action( 'init', 'homepage_slider', 0 );
```

I have queried both the fact that it is indeed the homepage and the main query is indeed running. Really weird error.

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I think something's wrong with the `add_my_post_types_to_query` function as it's not working with another Custom Post Type either.

Comment: Try to use `is_front_page()` instead of `is_home()`

Comment: how do you register the post type? **before** init or **after**?

Comment: It's before, in the order I've copied it.

Comment: Try `$query->is_home()`, you used the global function - i think that makes an new WP_Query

Comment: show `var_dump( $query->is_main_query() )` the result

Comment: Adrian, that didn't help unfortunately.

Tamil, here. It says the variable is undefined.

Notice: Undefined variable: query in /myfile/ on line 13

Fatal error: Call to a member function is_main_query() on a non-object in /myfile/ on line 13

Comment: Have you tried debugging? https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress

Comment: Yes, I have, but no errors are coming up

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing:

```
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'homepage_slider' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

With:

```
function add_my_post_types_to_query( $query ) {
    if ( $query->is_home() && $query->is_main_query() )
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'homepage_slider' ) );
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but still nothing.. What I find really weird was that it was working fine before. I don't know exactly when it stopped as I was working on another page, but I was adding another Custom Post Type at the time. Even if I remove the new one it still won't show up though.

Comment: Go to Settings -> Permalinks and hit save.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here's how I fixed it. Not quite a natural fix, but it did the job.

I simply created a new loop that runs through the custom post type wherever it must be placed and repeat for every other custom field I have on the homepage.

:)